# Failure to demangle symbol name in library (nm, objdump, c++filt)

Tags: c++, objdump, name-mangling, nm, c++filt

I noticed non-demangled functions in my output of `perf script` and originally thought `perf` might be doing something wrong.
But, looking deeper into some of the `*.so` files, I've been able to reproduce the problem with `c++filt -t`, `nm -C`, and `objdump -D -C`.

I'm a bit lost as to what could possibly be going wrong in the demangling process.
One of the symbols that isn't getting demangled is:

```
_ZZNK5Gaudi10Functional7details16MultiTransformerIFSt5tupleIJSt6vectorIN4LHCb14VPLightClusterESaIS6_EESt5arrayIjLm53EEEERK12EventContextRKNS5_8RawEventERK4DeVPENS0_6Traits4use_IJNS5_7DetDesc21useConditionHandleForIJSI_EEENSM_11BaseClass_tINSO_23ConditionAccessorHolderI10FixTESPathINS_9AlgorithmEEEEEEEEELb0EE7executeESE_ENKUlDpRT_E_clIJK21DataObjectWriteHandleIS8_S8_EKS15_ISA_SA_EEEEDaS12_
```

The library was compiled with GCC 10.1. But if I compile with clang 11, I can find the same symbol in `objdump -D -C`.

I'm a bit at a dead end now, so any suggestions as to what I could possibly check would be really appreciated. :)

Comment: Bugs/obsolete versions. Try https://github.com/nico/demumble

Comment: Thanks @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. ! That one worked :)

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by using the tool suggested in the comments.

`llvm-cxxfilt` also works and might be already available on some machines.

`c++filt`, `nm`, `perf`, and `objdump` use functionality that is implemented in libiberty which is part of GCC.
Thus I've filed a bug report there: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=102851