# nm and c++filter cannot demangle very long mangled c++ names?

Tags: c++, nm, c++filt

when experimenting c++ template meta-programming, I constructed a template type that is recursively defined, which makes type name very long in mangled form(~4600 bytes) if recursion depth is greater than 4, both `nm -C` and `c++filt` can not demangle the long name. Is this a limitation of `nm` and `c++filt` or the limitation of underlying libary used for demangling?

Edit:
After I posted this question, I tried the same thing on my MacBook,
it turned out the on MacOs, nm and c++filt works properly for the very long mangled name.

Comment: I recommend adding the template, the operating system, the compiler and version, the supporting tool chain, and the build command used so that we can see what you see and experiment.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/643777/is-there-any-limit-on-line-length-when-pasting-to-a-terminal-in-linux

Answer (score 1):

There is a `c++filt` [bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=97091) about demangling a variadic auto lambda. You could give `llvm-cxxfilt` a try.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69641274